# Xamarin Forms MapRenderer OnMapReady event equivalent for iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, custom-renderer

I need an equivalent event for an iOS renderer:

```
public class MyMapRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer
{
    ...

    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        // need to do things here
    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MKMapViewDelegate_MapLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mapkit.mkmapviewdelegate_extensions.maploaded?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#MapKit_MKMapViewDelegate_Extensions_MapLoaded_MapKit_IMKMapViewDelegate_MapKit_MKMapView_) to handle your actions in iOS renderer:

```
 public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;

            nativeMap.MapLoaded += NativeMap_MapLoaded;

        }

        private void NativeMap_MapLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NativeMap_MapLoaded");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Precisely! Thanks Jack Hua